# I am not able to concatenate variable in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making some changes to an existing Wordpress theme.

```
public function checkTv( $post ) {
         global $title;
        if ( ! empty( $post['season'] ) ) { 
            $videourl ='shows'.$title. $post['season'].'-'. $post['episodio'];
        }

        return $videourl;
    }
```

Here the `$videourl` contains the desired URL format. Everything is working but the `$title` value is not being concatenated in the URL. It is being skipped automatically. In title i have the slug.

This how the call is being made

```
$postmeta = doo_postmeta_episodes($post_id);
$videourl = $this->checkTv( $postmeta );
```

`$title` has been declared as global and the value of the title is being taken from a function.

Comment: Where is the value of `$title` set?

Comment: you don't have `$title` variable in this method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: _“$title has been declared as global”_ - no it has not, that would require the `global` keyword _inside_ your function.

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not skip the `$title` variable: It is undefined in your function and therefore empty. To use a variable which is defined outside the function you need to put the `global` directive inside of your function:

```
public function checkTv($post) {
    global $title;
    //...
}
```

This informs the function that the `$title` you're about to use is the same as the one declared outside the function.

Comment: sir its still not concatenating $title to the $videourl. Can you help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$videourl = 'shows'
    . get_the_title($post) 
    . '-' 
    . $post['season'] 
    . '-' 
    . $post['episodio'];
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the comment that you stated you need slug instead of title, try this:

```php
$slug = get_post_field('post_name', $post);
$videourl = 'shows' 
    . $slug
    . '-' 
    . $post['season'] 
    . '-' 
    . $post['episodio'];
```

Comment: sir this works but its giving the title as hello world. I need slug. Which is in url.

Comment: hey can you check my code with anydesk ? it would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I solved it. The Problem was with the scope but declaring it global was not solving it. I passed a another parameter with $post in the function that I got from $post_id and it solved the problem.
thanks for your efforts